# How to display decimal value from firestore database to android studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to show the points from my firestore database unto my android application but it only shows whole number instead of actually including the decimal numbers.
Firestore database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyexJ.jpg
Android application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zffM3.jpg

I have read previous posts about format("#.##") or
DecimalFormat("#,###.####")
but I'm not entirely sure how to apply that to my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView powents;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        ImageView qrimage = findViewById(R.id.qrimage);
        powents = findViewById(R.id.powents);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String mail = user.getEmail();
            DocumentReference docref = fStore.collection("Users").document(mail);
            docref.addSnapshotListener(this, (documentSnapshot, error) -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    powents.setText(String.valueOf(Math.toIntExact(documentSnapshot.getLong("Points"))));
                }
            });
        }
        try {
            BarcodeEncoder barcode = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcode.encodeBitmap(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getEmail(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 650, 650);
            qrimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged Out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
            finish();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Going forward, please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Understood! Apologies for my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is explicitly asking Firestore for a long (integer) value:

```
documentSnapshot.getLong("Points")
```

That's not what you want.  You want a double (floating point) value instead using [getDouble()](https://documentSnapshot.getLong(%22Points%22)):

```
documentSnapshot.getDouble("Points")
```

You can then turn that into a string for your TextView.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response I tried changing to getDouble but android studio gives me this error 'toIntExact(long)' in 'java.lang.Math' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Double)'

Comment: That's the same problem again: you should stop converting the value to an integer if you want the exact value of a double, and thus remove the `toIntExact()` call from your code.

Comment: Oh my, that fixed it! Silly me, sorry for the newbie mistakes. And thank you so much for the fast and straight forward explanation!